# Why is this Hardhat script that attempts a function call on a deployed contract throwing the error?

Tags: solidity, javascript, ethers.js, hardhat

I expect I should be able to easily call a function on my contract using this code in a script.js file:

```
const {ethers} = require("hardhat");

async function main() {
  console.log(`network: ${JSON.stringify(await ethers.provider.getNetwork())}`); //logs chainId is 31337 as expected
  const address = "0xe7f1725E7734CE288F8367e1Bb143E90bb3F0512"; //this is the address of the deployed NFTFactory contract
  const validAddress = ethers.utils.getAddress(address);
  console.log(validAddress); // should log the same address if it is valid, and it does
  const nftFactory = await ethers.getContractAt("NFTFactory", address);
  const implementation = await nftFactory.getImpl(); // THIS LINE THROWS
}

main()
  .then(() => process.exit(0))
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error(error)
    process.exit(1)
  })
```

But I get an error

```
Error: call revert exception [ See: https://links.ethers.org/v5-errors-CALL_EXCEPTION ] (method="getImpl()", data="0x", errorArgs=null, errorName=null, errorSignature=null, reason=null, code=CALL_EXCEPTION, version=abi/5.7.0) ...
```

Here is the contract/function I'm trying to call (irrelevant lines removed):

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.2;

contract NFTFactory
{
    event NFTContractCreated (address nftContract, address owner, string baseURI);

    string public constant NFT_CONTRACT_CREATION = "NFT_CONTRACT_CREATION";
    address public immutable implementation;

    constructor(
        address _implementation
        )
    {
        implementation = _implementation;
    }

    function getImpl() public view returns(address) {
        return implementation;
    }
}
```

What might be the issue? If I compile/deploy the same contract in remix, the function executes successfully.

Edit: In case it helps, here is my hardhat.config.js

```
require("@nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox");
require("dotenv").config();
require("hardhat-deploy");

/** @type import('hardhat/config').HardhatUserConfig */
module.exports = {
  defaultNetwork: "hardhat",
  networks: {
    localhost: {
      url: "http://127.0.0.1:8545/",
      //accounts: provided by hardhat
      chainId: 31337
    }
  },
  namedAccounts: {
    deployer: {
        default: 0, // here this will by default take the first account as deployer
    },
  },
  solidity: "0.8.18"
};
```

Edit2/Solution: I was running my script using "yarn hardhat run scripts/script.js". Guided by the comments and proposed answer I confirmed that the contract(s) didn't exist on the network that my script would have been interacting with (from my config file I believe this would have been the 'defaultNetwork' of 'hardhat'). I instead ran "yarn hardhat run --network localhost scripts/script.js" and the function call succeeded. Thanks all for the help.

Comment: Where is this contract deployed? You only have a local network in your config file.

Comment: Where did you deploy this contract before?

Comment: It was my understanding that running hardhat scripts causes a new instance of a local blockchain to be spun-up and the contracts deployed to it -  in this case chainId 31337. I could be misunderstanding this so will investigate.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the address `0xe7f1725E7734CE288F8367e1Bb143E90bb3F0512` may be incorrect.

I searched for this address across many networks, and the only instance where it was associated with a contract (a ERC20) was found here:

https://testnet.bttcscan.com/token/0xe7f1725e7734ce288f8367e1bb143e90bb3f0512#code

You can also verify by yourself at: https://blockscan.com/address/0xe7f1725e7734ce288f8367e1bb143e90bb3f0512

It functions on Remix because the contract exists there. However, the address you are attempting to call doesn't contain any contracts with the `getImpl()` function.

Comment: That's surprising an unrelated contract shares the address, but I got that address from the logs by running 'yarn hardhat node' which displays ""NFTFactory" ... deployed at 0xe7f1725E7734CE288F8367e1Bb143E90bb3F0512 with 411235 gas". Thus because I thought running the script spins-up the same local blockchain and with the same deployments, that the address stays the same.

Comment: to make sure that your contract is deployed call this method:
`await provider.getCode("0xe7f1725E7734CE288F8367e1Bb143E90bb3F0512");`